# Is there a way for a Lambda function to be triggered by multiple S3 buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create a Lambda function that will be triggered by any change made to any bucket in the S3 console. Is there a way to tie all create events from every bucket in S3 to my Lambda function?

It appears that in the creation of a Lambda function, you can only select one S3 bucket. Is there a way to do this programmatically, if not in the Lambda console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least one way: you can setup an s3 event notifications, for each bucket you want to monitor, all pointing to a single SQS queue.

That SQS queue can then be the event source for your lambda function.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with SNS topics? I'm trying to set up a Lambda function that will send notifications to bucket owners if their buckets are found to be public.

Comment: I haven't done it that way, but SNS would probably work as well - s3 event notifications can goto SNS, and SNS can call lambda

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any aws-sdk to upload to s3 there is a workaround by setting up an API gateway endpoint to trigger lambda whenever the upload to s3 succeeded.
passing the bucket-name & object-key to lambda you may also specify the dest bucket dynamically.

This also will be helpful with nested prefixes.
e.g. 
bucket/users/avatars/user1.jpg
bucket/users/avatars/thumbnails/user1-thumb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, assume that you only want to trigger Lambda if there're new created objects in a few buckets, you can do it via AWS Console, cli, boto3 & other SDK.

If over time there're new bucket created & you also want to add it as event source for Lambda, you can create a Cloudtrail API event source to trigger another Lambda to programmaticallyy dd these new buckets as event sources for the original Lambda.