# Multiple s3 bucket object creation event trigger same lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have requirement to trigger single lambda by object creation events in two s3 buckets and then copy them to respective tables in redshift.

I am new to AWs world.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Your pointer is AWS documentation for S3.

Comment: Here a post on how to trigger same lambda from multiple s3 buckets https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54556599/is-there-a-way-for-a-lambda-function-to-be-triggered-by-multiple-s3-buckets

Answer (score 0):

I can give you the idea.

There are two steps involved.

#### create the lambda

create the lambda in `c#` to handle events from S3. So that when an object is uploaded to the S3 bucket, the lambda function could be invoked. The following permissions should be configured on the lambda.

- Lambda to read from S3 bucket
  you can assign a policy to the IAM role to give read permission to the s3 bucket
- Lambda to be called from S3.
  The lambda's should have a trusted relationship with S3, so that the s3 can invoke the lambda. Basically the lambda's IAM role should have the trusted policy to allow s3 to invoke the lambda.

reference:

https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/compress-images-csharp-lambda-tinypng/

#### Setup the trigger on the S3 bucket.

You have to setup the `Object Created` trigger and configure the lambda function as the trigger.

Reference:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/aws_lambda/aws_lambda_using_lambda_function_with_amazon_s3.htm

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing the steps but i am aware how to trigger lambda by object create events in one s3 bucket.
My question was around can lambda be triggered at same time by two s3 buckets object create events.

Comment: Comments are a better place for commenting.